# When click a tag show alert - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code in HTML :

```
<td id ="tdtest">
    <a id="atest" href="#">
         <span id="spantest">Show</span>
    </a>
</td>
```

and Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#tdtest #atest").on('click',function(){
        alert ("Success !!!");

    })
}
```

But when i click "Show" , it's not working.

Comment: Do you have your jquery code wrapped in a DOM ready function?

Comment: why not just do `$("#spantest").on('click',function() {})`

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: @Ken99 what Carsten commented should work fine. Is the HTML being added to the DOM after the page loaded? Have you put your code in a document.ready event handler?

Comment: Inside a tag, its not possible to click its child.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a standalone `<td>` without a table and table row surrounding it. As soon as you write valid markup, it works:

```js
$("#tdtest #atest").on('click',function(){
    alert ("Success !!!");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="tdtest">
    <a id="atest" href="#">
      <span id="spantest">Show</span>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As suggested in other answers already, an ID is already a unique identifier for a DOM element, so there's actually no need to use two ids in a selector and it might even internally slow down finding the correct node.

Answer (score 1):

use `div` the place of `td` and your code is working.

```
<div id ="tdtest">
    <a id="atest" href="#">
         <span id="spantest">Show</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#tdtest #atest").on('click',function(){
      alert ("Success !!!");
   });
});
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/05m77ocx/)

Answer (score 0):

1. only use one id in selector
2. put code after document ready, `$(function(){ code here.. })`

```js
$(function(){
  $("#atest").on('click',function(){
    alert ("Success !!!");

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td id="tdtest">
    <a id="atest">
         <span id="spantest">Show</span>
    </a>
</td>
```